# O que é FastExpando/FastExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, reflexão, dapper

Estava [lendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948193/5429980) a respeito do Dapper e me deparei com uma característica dele chamada **FastExpando** ou **FastExpandoObject**, eu não compreendi muito bem e fiquei com algumas duvidas em relação a esta característica.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é FastExpando/FastExpandoObject?
2. Qual é a relação que o FastExpando/FastExpandoObject tem com o Dapper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Primeiro, na framework .NET existe a classe ExpandoObject**, que permite a expansão de um objeto em tempo de execução.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

ExpandoObject tem vários usos, um deles é no acesso a Banco de Dados, armazenando os resultados de uma consulta. A habilidade de alterar o objeto mostra-se muito útil nessa tarefa.

Dapper, em sua própria definição, é um framework simples para manipular objetos em .NET, que tem como objetivo oferecer uma melhor performance.

- http://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

**Agora, sobre FastExpandoObject**, eu não o encontrei na definição original  do Dapper (link acima).

Encontrei-o em um repositório do GitHub:

- http://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Helpers

onde é declarado como:

```
private class FastExpando : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>
```

No SqlMapper.cs desse repositório, existe uma referência a uma página antiga:

- http://code.google.com/archive/p/dapper-dot-net/

E essa página possui um pacote antigo do Dapper, mas o mesmo também não possui nenhuma definição do FastExpando:

- http://code.google.com/archive/p/dapper-dot-net/source/default/source

**Concluindo,** como a pergunta original que te deixou com dúvida é de 2012, eu imagino que FastExpandoObject não seja mais utilizado. E, julgando pelo nome, tinha como propósito ser mais rápido que o ExpandoObject.

Pesquisando sobre ExpandoObject, eu encontrei uma outra classe chamada BetterExpando, que em sua definição é "melhor que expando".

- http://gist.github.com/lukevenediger/6327599

E provavelmente devem existir outras classes...

Answer (score 6):

[ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) são objetos dinâmicos, ou seja, objetos que voce pode adicionar ou remover propriedades em tempo de execução.

```
dynamic meuCache;
meuCache.QualquerCoisa = "Qualquer coisa mesmo";
meuCache.OutraCoisa = new { FaladoSerio = true };
meuCache.MaisUmaCoisa = Enum.Empty<string>();
```

Hoje, o objeto dinamico mais popular do .NET Framework é o [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx), do [ASP.NET MVC](https://asp.net).

No caso do [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), ele utiliza objetos dinamicos para deserializar informações que virão de uma fonte onde seu formato é desconhecido.

Podemos ver sua aplicação no Dapper em sua classe [GridReader](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/ce1ce8d7b335e42f0c455bd34fcb148129d77ac8/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.cs), método `.Read(bool)`

> **class GridReader**: The grid reader provides interfaces for reading multiple result sets from a Dapper query
>
> **IEnumerable < dynamic> GridReader.Read(bool)**: Read the next grid of results, returned as a dynamic object

[Retornar listas é sempre melhor do que retornar tabelas](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/).